# Firebase Cloud Functions DeltaSnapshot Parent Access

Tags: database, firebase, parent-child, snapshot, google-cloud-functions

I cannot find any way to query the database for a parent value of DeltaSnapshot, so I tried setting the event to trigger when anything in the entire database is changed. This seems to still trigger onWrite correctly, but trying to return the contents or key of any children returns a null value. I had the log print the value of DeltaSnapshot, and the entire database is there, and logging hasChild confirms that the children with the names I'm querying do in fact exist in the database, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong to only get null when I ask for the value/key of any specific child. Additionally, I was wondering if there is any way to do what I originally wanted and just jump up to the parents of DeltaSnapshot so that I don't have to trigger an onWrite every time anything in the database is changed.

Update: I cannot use ref or adminRef without causing an error. I am currently trying to get the value like this:

```
const nameIn;
nameIn = event.data.current.child('name/{pushId}').val();
console.log('User ID:', nameIn);
```

This prevents me from getting an error, but the log always returns null. My only guess is that it has to do with the function being run asynchronously to the database getting updated, but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting the trigger to the entire database, use event.data.adminRef to have unrestricted access to the database. You can find out more about adminRef in [the Cloud Functions Database documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DeltaSnapshot).